# How to convert datetime attribute into unix timestamp attribute?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to upgrade my database table by changing the datatype of the column "date_added" from

```
`date_added` datetime DEFAULT NULL
```

to

```
`new_date_added` bigint(20) NOT NULL
```

`date_added` has datetime values stored in the format "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS". This database table has more than 15000 rows. What is the best way to perform this modification?

Note: I have tried executing following MySql query :

```
ALTER TABLE  `my_table` ADD  `new_date_added` bigint(20) NOT NULL AFTER  `date_added`;
UPDATE `my_table` SET new_date_added = UNIX_TIMESTAMP(  `date_added` );
ALTER TABLE  `my_table` DROP `date_added`;
```

Above solution doesn't convert datetime value into correct unix_timestamp. If I compare UNIX timestamp created after the modification with its original datetime value, there is a diffrence of 19800 seconds.

Comment: datetime field already stored as unix timestamp internally in mysql

Comment: 19800 seconds = 5:30 hours. My bet: you are in India (GMT + 5:30)

Comment: What changes should i make in my sql queries so that it will create the right timestamp values?

Comment: I added an edit to my answer

Answer (score 3):

19800 seconds = 5:30 hours. You are probably located in India (GMT + 5:30).

`UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` generates timestamps that are [relative to GMT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp), so it is likely that your values are correct.

To get the right value back, you could e.g. use PHP's `date()` and [set the correct timezone.](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php)

Make sure, however, that you have a really good reason to move away from DATETIME in the first place. It's generally the superior format, allows for all kinds of optimized operations within mySQL, and is free from the [year 2038 problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem) that 32-bit timestamps have.

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution for my problem.
Following is the final working code which is giving me correct timestamps :

```
SET time_zone = "+00:00";
ALTER TABLE  `my_table` ADD  `new_date_added` bigint(20) NOT NULL AFTER  `date_added`;
UPDATE `my_table` SET new_date_added = UNIX_TIMESTAMP(  `date_added` );
ALTER TABLE  `my_table` DROP `date_added`;
```

@Ela Buwa: I have written the exact same code which is giving me an incorrect timestamp values (due to automatically adjusted/shifted timestamp values)

@Pekka: My question was about mysql's UNIX_TIMESTAMP() giving me unexpected values. Using PHP's date() function will not affect mysql's timezone settings. That is why i used `SET time_zone = "+00:00";` to configure mysql's timezone. Thank you for taking a time to answer my question though.

Thank you all for the efforts and sparing your valuable time.

Comment: This only *kind of* solves your problem though. You still have GMT timestamps - you just tricked mySQL into believing that the data you were importing were GMT, too. I guess it's workable if you really know what you're doing, but it's not an ideal solution (also are you really really sure you need to do this in the first place? What's wrong with DATETIME?)

Answer (score 1):

I'd use strtotime.
It says the time in the number of seconds passed since 1970-01-01 00:00:00

```
<?php
echo(strtotime("now") . "<br>");
echo(strtotime("3 October 2005") . "<br>");
echo(strtotime("+5 hours") . "<br>");
echo(strtotime("+1 week") . "<br>");
echo(strtotime("+1 week 3 days 7 hours 5 seconds") . "<br>");
echo(strtotime("next Monday") . "<br>");
echo(strtotime("last Sunday"));
?>
```

If you want to do it with in mysql, use
UPDATE table_name SET timefield=UNIX_TIMESTAMP(timefield);
I haven't tested it out though.
You might want to check the mysql documents here. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html